# True center align images inside a DIV on Hover

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that I have put images that show up on hover. This is no problem, but getting them aligned vertically and horizontally is the real problem. I have messed with it for a few hours and it just won’t cooperate with me. I have tried all sorts of CSS but to no avail. Can someone please help me?

Here the current project: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/1089/)

I tried the `padding:auto` and `vertical-align:middle` but neither worked.

I am trying to getthe image that appear on over to be vertically and horizontally aligned with the inner DIV. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is new updated `jsfiddle` see this.  i changed in your css

http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/Zf5am/1091/

Comment: You should add explanation to your answer